# Admins vs Users

Tags: mysql, database

I've been searching for a while now and it seems that most answers are saying to use a single table for users and admins, to just identify their role through a column named "role".

I can't seem to figure out the logic behind that answer. Since on my current project, I planned to have a separate domain for admins (CMS) and users. Also, my users table has like 10 columns in which only 5 columns of it will be needed for the admins table.

With that, is it still preferable to use a single table for users and admins?

Comment: Is an admin a user?

Comment: *is it still preferable to use a single table for users and admins?* Depends on the system and its analysis. If "admin" is really separate entity (not only special property of the user) then separate table may be suitable (and it should refer to users table - because admin is a kind of user, is it?). But maybe a table with special "for admins only" attributes referred to users table is enough...

Comment: It depends: are your admins a subset of your users, or are they a completely distinct set of persons? See the linked answer.